# [verb]Json() methods in tests are not obeying the config('app.url') after upgrading to 7.x

Tags: php, laravel

I have upgraded the laravel version to 7.17.2 from 6.16.0 a few minutes ago following the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade).

But my tests are now failing with the following exception: `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException : POST http://localhost/v1/orders`

The `APP_URL` is set to `http://localhost` in my `.env` file. But in my base TestCase class, I am overriding the config('app.url') with a custom endpoint. Before the upgrade, the tests were picking the custom endpoint.

Since the last upgrade, apparently the getJson(), postJson(), etc helper methods are not applying the URL from `config('app.url')` but directly from the `.env` file. Because when I hardcode the URL in the `.env` file, I no longer get the NotFoundHttpException.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following.

In your phpunit.xml:

```
<php>
    <server name="APP_URL" value="http://example.com"/>
</php>
```

Or in your TestCase:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    URL::forceRootUrl('http://example.com');
}
```

Both of these will result in `app('url')->to('my-endpoint')` printing `http://example.com/my-endpoint`

Comment: Had to go forceRootUrl() route because I needed to programmatically append a string to it which I don't think is possible in xml.